# comic sans font not showing on mobile

Tags: android, css, mobile, fonts

I recently built a comics website at [www.pipanni.com](http://www.pipanni.com) that uses the "Comic Sans" font. Everything is ok so far, except that the font is not showing on my Samsung Galaxy mobile phone. It shows something that looks like Arial.

I've already tried every clear history / cache, etc.

Here's my styles font:
body
{
    font-family: "comic sans ms", "comic sans", "Comic Sans", arial, helvetica, tahoma, verdana;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000000;
}

The home page's title is working ok on my laptop (and every other computer I've tested the website on), but not on my smartphone.

I don't have an iphone, but I think it is working ok on those.

What can I try next?

P.S: This is a comics website, it's supposed to use "Comic Sans"! :)

Answer (score 5):

I just found the simple solution for this, you just need to override the font file using font face like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Comic Sans MS';
  src: url("comic-sans-ms/comici.ttf");
}
```

and HTML code

```
<h1 style="font-family: 'Comic Sans MS';">Comic sans</h1>
```

What happen is browser will override the default font file by using your file. In any devices, the browser will download `comici.ttf` and render the same font.

p/s: font file you can download from here https://www.wfonts.com/font/comic-sans-ms

Answer (score 1):

To display a font, the device must have this font installed. If not, it uses the fallback you gave to it ( here Arial).

If you want to include a specific font, you can user websites like google font or you could use @Font-face ( look here : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp )

But be aware that you need the rights to use and install that font.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But is @font-face necessary for default fonts? I thought Comic Sans was one of them.

Comment: Comic Sans is not a default font for every device.  For example, Comic Sans is not a default font on Mac. So you can't just can't count on that. 
By the way, after a quick look, "Comic Sans Neue" don't need any attribution to be used on a website with @font-face. Check here :

http://comicneue.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try this asap.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept my answer if this solve your problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

checkout out font-squirrel. They have an app that will allow you to change a font like comic sans into an embedded font. Very handy for ensuring your look is consistent across all devices.

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Go to expert settings and choose base64encode.

It will create a css file that has the embedded font which you include on your css.